# How do I update a sharedpreference variable in this way?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a sharedpreference var with values like these:

```
key0,value
key1,value
key3,value
key5,value
key6,value
key7,value
key10,value
```

What I want to do is to get a new sharedpreference value with items sorted sequentially like these:

```
key0,value
key1,value
key2,value
key3,value
key4,value
key5,value
key6,value
```

How do I do this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: did you tried something? put that here.

Comment: No, I didn't try anything. Is because of that I put this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround like this:

```
SharedPreferences shp = context.getSharedPreferences("yourSHP", MODE_PRIVATE);

//begin & end are to integers. For your case: 0 and 6 to get form key0 to key6
for(int i=begin;i<=end;i++){
 String value = shp.getString("key"+i, "defaultValue");
 //.....Here you can do whatever you want with your values
}
```

I hope this would help!!

Comment: But this code doesn't update sharedpreference inside the loop. I want to update the key name with the second option I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();

for( Entry<String, String> entry : testMap.entrySet() ) 
  editor.putString( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );

editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to make this a more useful answer - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following workaround. I don't know if there is another faster way to do it:

```
            SharedPreferences shpTH = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PrefsTH", ListadoImagenesSubidasMain.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Map<String,?> keysTH = shpTH.getAll();

            List<String> imgTH = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keysTH.entrySet()){
                  imgTH.add(entry.getValue().toString());          
            }

            SharedPreferences newPrefsTH = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PrefsTH", ListadoImagenesSubidasMain.MODE_PRIVATE);
            newPrefsTH.edit().clear().commit();

            int contTH = 0;
            for(String item : imgTH){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editorTH = newPrefsTH.edit();
                editorTH.putString("urlTH" + contTH, item);
                editorTH.commit();
                contTH++;
            }
```

Firstly I copy all the values to a list. Then I empty the sharedpreferences var and finally I put all the values got from the list filled previously in the empty sharedpreferences.